# Writing special characters to xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am using LINQ to XML to write an element to an xml document. The problem i am having is that the string i try to write to the xml element has characters such as &, <, > and ".

When i write it to xml using the following code,

```
XElement Config= new XElement("Student", new XElement("ID", "><&\""));
```

I dont get these special characters being written to the XML document. Instead i get things like `&lt; for < and &gt; for >`. How can i escape these characters while writing them to xml?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me your asking it to do what it already does?

Comment: `&lt;`  is the escaped version of `<`

Comment: Ok then how do i print the character < exactly as it is in the xml?

Comment: That is just c# enforcing well formed XML. the escaped characters are changed back to their original value when you read from the XML file, at least in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XDocument escapes them itself.

`<Student><ID>><&"</ID></Student>` isn't well-formed XML.

Well-formed version, which produces XDocument is:

```
<Student>
  <ID>&gt;&lt;&amp;"</ID>
</Student>
```

You can use this code (uses CDATA):

```
XElement Config = new XElement("Student", new XElement("ID", new XCData("><&\"")));
```

Output:

```
<Student>
  <ID><![CDATA[><&"]]></ID>
</Student>
```

Comment: well i want it to print to xml exactly what i write inside the double quotes. Like in the end, i want to see the characters ><& in the xml

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk - I'd give you +2 if I could for persistence.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to achieve is file like this:

```
<Student>
  <ID>><&\</ID>
</Student>
```

Then you're doing it wrong. It's not a well-formed XML and no parser is going to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to be output using escaped characters - then use a StringBuilder or StreamWriter.

The fact is, though, you're trying to generate bad XML that will not be parseable by any XML reader so there's actually no point - unless you are deliberately trying to break someone's XML handling!?